# How to change the duplex of a NIC remotely on windows?

Tags: windows, networking, nic

I want to change remotely on windows xp the speed/duplex of a NIC. I try with mmc, netsh but without result. I have to log me in with rdp to change the duplex, or remotely search in the registry and modify the value manually.

Does anyone know a way to change this without modifying the registry manually?

Answer (score 2):

One workaround is to use psexec from Sysinternals to modify the registry remotely or use reg add and specify remote computer:

REG ADD \Remotecomputer\HKLM\Software....  /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d ^%systemroot^%

Do not forget to also force the other side, else big mess around the corner

Comment: Duplex mismatches are far to common. This seems like a problem we should have licked by now. Good work around +1.

Comment: they have solved this problem. Gigabit Ethernet and newer are all full duplex.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, assuming it's connected to a managed switch - change the duplex mode on the switch. The ethernet adapter (should!) will then sort itself to the new mode. You might have to disable/enable the switch port.

(Insert abandoned server disclaimer here)

Mike

Comment: this is wrong. You must be auto/auto on both side, or manually set on both side. Auto versus full duplex will lead the auto side to be half duplex, and so packet loss will occurs. This is a common mistake on network auto negocation.